# Use 20230821 date format instead of 08aug2023 at top of ado and sthlp file

Tags: package, stata, ado

I am writing a utility that helps maintain Stata packages intended to be published on GitHub and/or on SSC. It is not published yet, so documentation is lacking but the repo is public so if anyone is curious here is a link: https://github.com/lsms-worldbank/adodown. This is part of the `ad_publish` command.

The tool I am currently working on makes the manual process of updating version and dates at the header of the ado and sthlp file automatic. My question is on the format of the date.

Ado files typically have something like this on the first line:

- `*! version 3.31  26apr2022  Ben Jann` (estout)
- `*! version 6.12.3 08aug2023` (reghdfe)

And sthlp(/hlp) files:

- `{* 01feb2017}{...}` (estout)
- `{* *! version 6.12.3 08aug2023}{...}` (reghdfe)

Can the date be on a different format? In the .pkg file there is this line `d Distribution-Date: 20230821` (reghdfe) where the date is always on that format. Here is Stata's [documentation](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/rnet.pdf) on pkg files that consistently using the `20230821` format. Although it does not explicitly say that any format is required.

So my question is, does anyone see a reason to not use `20230821` format in the header of ado and sthlp files? (Apart from our American friends being confused when month comes before day :) ). I think this date format is in this context better, as `20230821` can be sorted alphanumerically to get sort the dates which `08aug2023` cannot.

For completion, this is the formats I intend to use. The only thing I am do not feel confident will work well is the date format.

- Ado: `*! version V.V YYYYMMDD <author> <contact>`
- Sthlp: `{* *! version V.V YYYYMMDD }{...}`

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it Stata doesn't care one bit what you put after `*!`. It simply looks for lines beginning that way and echoes them given a `which` query.

In contrast, I think the routines used for maintenance of .pkg files on SSC standardize on the date format 20240213 for Kit Baum's convenience.

In my own commands, I have usually followed the date format I used previously for the same command, whether 13feb2024 or 13 Feb 2024 or 13 February 2024. In 30 years of writing ados I have not heard a single whisper that any date format was problematic to anyone else, and I can not imagine any problems with your format beyond possibly unwillingness for third parties to adopt.

I don't use and can't comment on GitHub.